# Something in my build process is introducing a syntax error, regarding globalThis.process.env.NODE_ENV

Tags: vite, quasar

So, using Quasar, and picking up a project I haven't messed with in a week or two, I cannot get it to compile properly.  When I execute "quasar dev" as per usual, the site fails to build:

`[Quasar] boot error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string (at chunk-S3UJV3FY.js?v=56d0515d:1070:51)`

The offending line renders as:

`var instanceOf = globalThis.process && globalThis."development" === "production" ? function ...`

I traced this line to the instanceOf part of jsutils, as used by graphql.  The original line is:

`const instanceOf = globalThis.process && globalThis.process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? function ...`

So, right away, I can see that some part of the build process has changed, and `process.env.NODE_ENV` is being blindly replaced by `"development"`, but I cannot figure out why.

There's nothing in the git history related to the local dev process, and I've tried clearing out node_modules, and the quasar build cache. I had been messing with `unplugin-auto-import`, but i've uninstalled it, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug somewhere in graphql:

https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/16060

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/3919

I solved it by fixing graphql's verison:

> "graphql": "16.6.0",

vs

> "graphql": "^16.6.0",

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to vite version 4 solved my issue